# Preventing Listview items from overlapping

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView which - when I add items into the layout, when the items reaches the bottom - is overlapping some Button I placed at the bottom of the view.
See this screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I want to add the items to my ListView using all the available space above the Buttons as these are the last Views (preventing to show the items the user won't see).

Listview setup:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/log_drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/log_drawer_color"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0.0dip"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey19"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_state_config"
            android:text="@string/clear_log"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/clear_log"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="41dp" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/share_log"
            android:text="@string/share_log"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_state_config"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clear_log"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clear_log"
            android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="73dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

More information can be provided, if needed. Thanks.

Comment: use android:layout_above="ur second relative layout id" for ur listview

Comment: Why did you put the 2 buttons **inside another RelativeLayout**?! Please,  **avoid layout nesting**!!

Comment: I didn't layout nest. The are required to set those buttons at the buttom of the listview

Comment: It is **not required**, if you know how to use a RelativeLayout **properly**. So, please **get rid** of useless **layout nesting**.

Comment: Even if I remove that layout and align my buttons with one relativelayout that hasn't solved my issue

Comment: Let me show you how I do such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having issues like this in the near future, this is how I solved mine
I added to my listview

```
android:layout_above="@+id/layout_id "
 android:scrollbars="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following property to your ListView:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

which will make is scrollable and won't override other elements.

Or, you can do it programatically:

```
listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: The items added to the listview are still overlapping with the buttons

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use LinearLayout for your issue.

Consider following code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

     <ListView
    android:id="@+id/log_drawer"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="@color/log_drawer_color"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0.0dip"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

       <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_state_config"
        android:text="@string/clear_log"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:id="@+id/clear_log"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/share_log"
        android:text="@string/share_log"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_state_config"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clear_log"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clear_log"
        android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="73dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple design, using a single RelativeLayout.
The ListView will stay **above** the buttons.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_state_config"
        android:text="@string/clear_log"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:id="@+id/clear_log"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/share_log"
        android:text="@string/share_log"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_state_config"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clear_log"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clear_log"
        android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="73dp"
    />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/log_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_above="@id/clear_log"
        android:background="@color/log_drawer_color"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0.0dip"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This would cause the buttons to fill the whole layout without showing the listview. So this doesn't work.

Comment: Obviously, **this is false**. Since they are set to `wrap_content`, which causes them to occupy **only the space needed by their content**. Therefore, this arrangement **does work**. I have a certain experience in UI design, you can trust me.